# String modification trigger is not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a trigger that executes after the INSERT completes on only newly inserted rows (I do not need to execute on old rows). The trigger should modify inserted string using split_part and replace functions.

The queries are as follows:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS date_extraction ON t32upb

drop function if exists date_extraction();
CREATE FUNCTION date_extraction() RETURNS trigger AS $$
begin

  NEW.filename := replace(split_part(old.filename,'_', 2), '.tif', '');

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER
  date_extraction
AFTER INSERT on 
  sentinel_2.t32upb
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE
  date_extraction();
```

What is wrong with the query? it is not working

Comment: What's wrong is you did not read the documentation [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html): "The return value of a row-level trigger fired AFTER or a statement-level trigger fired BEFORE or AFTER is always ignored; it might as well be null. "

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thanks for the comment. Can you pleas guide what should I change?

Comment: Read the doc link I posted, it has the answers.

Comment: You need to change `AFTER` to `BEFORE`

Comment: Even once you correct for when trigger fires, it will still not do what you want (most likely). You set the value of new.filename using old.filename. Unfortunately for an Insert trigger `old.filename` is always null. Thus `split_part(old.filename,'_', 2)` will be null so the resulting `new.filename` will always be null; might as well write `new.filename = null;`. Perhaps you need to explain what you are attempting to accomplish.